# setting column to null in case statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I am trying to do a select statement where if a local bit variable is 0 then there needs to be a condition when a column is null. I cant figure out how to do it without doing a `column1 = NULL` which does not give the correct result:

```
DECLARE @s bit = 0
SELECT pkID FROM table1 WHERE column1 = CASE WHEN @s = 0 THEN NULL ELSE column1 END
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: You say *setting* a column to `NULL`, but your query is a `SELECT` statement.  Please clarify your intent with some sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding both conditions to the `WHERE` clause:

```
Declare @s Bit = 0;
Select  pkID
From    table1
Where   (@S = 0 And Column1 Is Null)
Or      (@S <> 0)
```